# How can I force a ListBox to fill entire free area?

Tags: gwt

I put a ListBox into a tabele cell an want it to ocupy the whole cell (width="100% height="100%") and show as many rows as possible but:

- not specifyng setVisibleItemCount causes to show a big dropdownbox (i want a list)
- specifying setVisibleCout makes listbox to ignore height (it takes as much place as it needet to exacly display n rows)

i there a workaround ? (in Swing a number of wisible rows ia a funcion of height and I'd like it this way in gwt).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListBox is a native GWT component, and that's the way it works. If you're using GWT 2.1 you can create your own CellRenderer

Comment: @Ibownik That really depends of what you want to do. As I said, in GWT 2.1 you have the new Cell Widgets.
If you don't want or cannot upgrade, then I would suggest you to create your own using a VerticalPanel or another FlexTable

Answer (score 0):

You could approximate a solution by calculating how many items should be shown based on the height you want.